# connection error in mongodb how to handel this error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-query, e-commerce

err = new ServerSelectionError();
^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at _handleConnectionErrors (E:\woxaa\woxaa\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:755:11)
at NativeConnection.openUri (E:\woxaa\woxaa\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:730:11)
at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'Unknown',
servers: Map(1) {
'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
address: 'localhost:27017',
type: 'Unknown',
hosts: [],
passives: [],
arbiters: [],
tags: {},
minWireVersion: 0,
maxWireVersion: 0,
roundTripTime: -1,
lastUpdateTime: 67139425,
lastWriteDate: 0,
error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at connectionFailureError (E:\woxaa\woxaa\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:383:20)
at Socket. (E:\woxaa\woxaa\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:307:22)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
errno: -4078,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '::1',
port: 27017
},
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
},
topologyVersion: null,
setName: null,
setVersion: null,
electionId: null,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
primary: null,
me: null,
'$clusterTime': null
}
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: null,
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined
}

how to  handle this error

Answer (score 0):

**connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017** suggests that the server at the address **localhost:27017** refused the connection.

Some ideas why this could be happening

- The MongoDB server is running on a different port or address. Check the MongoDB server configuration to make sure you are connecting to the correct address and port.
- The MongoDB server is not running at all.
- Firewall might be blocking the connection. Check any firewall or network security settings to make sure that the connection is allowed.
- There might be an issue with MongoDB driver or configuration. Check your code and configuration to make sure that everything is set up correctly.